# How to discover what exceptions can be thrown in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, exception

While using [`wreq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq) recently, I wrote code that compiled and worked for a while. Then, a `HttpException` was thrown. `HttpException` is not defined in `wreq`. I had to track it down to `http-client`. Then, a while later again, `JSONError` was thrown. This is also not defined in `wreq` but in `aeson`.

How do I find out what possible exceptions can be thrown from a black box library other than to read through all available documentation for that library, and possibly all dependent libraries, hoping that the authors had mentioned it?

Comment: You don't that's why using exceptions is usually a bad practice. Usually `Either` and `Maybe`, or `ExceptT` are used for computations that might fail. Here the documentation mentions the `HttpException` and `JsonError` however: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.5.3.2/docs/Network-Wreq.html

Comment: I reject the implicit assumption that "read the documentation" is an unreasonable expectation.

Comment: You may be able to trust that a given library's code is executing correctly by examining the documentation and perhaps the tests. How much trust do you have that a given library's author has documented all exceptions? And, will you be also checking every dependent library's documentation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no means in Haskell for determining which runtime exceptions a function might throw.

If you're coming from Java with its "checked" and "unchecked" exceptions, then you should consider all Haskell runtime exceptions to be unchecked.  The Haskell equivalent of checked exceptions is usually to incorporate them into the result type using `Maybe`, `Either`, `ExceptT`, or something similar, as mentioned in the comments.

There are different views on appropriate uses of unchecked, runtime exceptions versus these other mechanisms, and library authors will make different decisions about error handling, so you're kind of at their mercy.

In this case, the documentation for `wreq` makes it very clear that `HttpException` and `JSONError` can be thrown, but there's no guarantee that the documentation for this or any other library is correct/complete or that dependent libraries won't throw other exceptions that aren't listed.  (Note: `JSONError` is actually defined in `wreq`.  The `aeson` package doesn't use exceptions to signal JSON decoding errors.)

In production code, you'll want to make sure that you have an appropriate "all exceptions" handler in place.